# json question mark strange signs

Tags: php, sql, json

I generate json trough php, when I get the data in json, I get it in a strange way, sometimes with 2 question marks, like in example:

```
{"markers":[
{"latitude":"48.6916858",
"longitude":"13.9314643",
"content":"Ort Kn\u00f6belsteiner??<\/b>28.12.2014. - 12:00"}}]}
```

Here is the code that generates the json:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$row_array['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
$row_array['longitude'] = $row['longitude'];
$row_array['content'] = utf8_encode($row['grcnt']);

array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo '{"markers":'.json_encode($return_arr).'}';
```

I am not sure why am I getting this ?? signs. I tried to google it but no answer. I used json with sql queries combined with html tags, since I need to show this info on a mark (point) on the map. Sql result after query is shown normal, without this question marks. Any help would be appreciated since I am not really sure why is this and in which case it happens. Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code that produces this JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT! :)

the problem was in utf8_encode() line, I removed it and made a new query after the connection to the db, wrote this:

```
mysqli_query ( $link ,"SET NAMES 'utf8'" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You use json_encode? Php and javascript have diferent ways to see objects. Look at the second parameter of json_encode